# maya fbx camera flipped

Tags: camera, .fbx

I have no problem with a camera (animation baked) exported as Alembic from Maya however I can't get the keyframes from an abc. Using FBX solves the keyframes problem but it seems like the camera is flipped and looks backward.

I tried the different options available during import without success.

Is that a bug or is there anything I can do about it ?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Are you importing a camera from Maya to Blender ? Axes are not the same, Maya is Y up while Blender is Z up, it might be just that.

Comment: From Maya to Blender yes. I tried switching the axis yes, also I tried with some geo, the camera look the opposite way no matter what. The only way I found to fix it was to scale by -1 in both X and Z which is not an acceptable solution to me, I imagine there should be a further reason.